# How to have a textbox uniquely for a row dynamically?

Tags: angular, matrix, dynamic, textbox

I have created a matrix, which contains multiple textbox. I want textbox to be worked uniquely for the column. I am getting the data of row and column from the API nd then it has to getting added to the table.

Html file

```
<div class="card" *ngIf="inputQuestionType == 'matrixtextbox'">
    <div class="header custom-justify-content-space-between">
        <h2>{{QuestionDescription}}<span *ngIf="questionSettin[0].value" style="color: red;"> *</span></h2>
        <mat-icon matSuffix title="{{AnswerHint}}" *ngIf="AnswerHint && AnswerHint != ''">help_outline</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        <div *ngIf="dataValue.length > 0 && displayColumns.length >0">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataValue" style="width: 100%;">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="question">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row=index">{{dataValue[row]}}</td>
          </ng-container>
          
            <ng-container
              *ngFor="let innerColumn of displayColumns;let i=index"
              [matColumnDef]="innerColumn">
            
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{displayColumns[i]}}</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let row=index">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                    <!-- <mat-label>Input</mat-label> -->
                    <input matInput type="text" autocomplete="off" (change)="radiochange($event)" [(ngModel)]="dataSer.previewQAns">
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="allColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: allColumns"></tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am adding the output image which I am getting below. When I enter a value in 1 textbox all the textbox are getting changed with the same imput.
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvBL7.png)

Comment: I imagine you need use in your ngModel: some like `[(ngModel)]="element[displayColumns[i]]"`. what is the way of your "dataValue" variable?

Comment: I solved it by using different ngmodel and different value for every textboc. Making it dynamically using index. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by assigning different value to different textbox. I have added  value dynamically and also added an name field to input tag. Which gives me different values so that I can use all textboxes uniquely.

```
<div class="body">
        <div *ngIf="dataValue.length > 0 && displayColumns.length >0">
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataValue" style="width: 100%;">
            <ng-container matColumnDef="question">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
          <td style="width: 10%;" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row=index">{{dataValue[row]}}</td>
          </ng-container>
          
            <ng-container
              *ngFor="let innerColumn of displayColumns;let i=index"
              [matColumnDef]="innerColumn">
            
              <th class="text-center" style="width: 20%;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{displayColumns[i]}}</th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element;let row=index">
                <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
                    <input matInput type="text" autocomplete="off"
                    [(ngModel)]="valueCheckboxMatrix[row][i]"
                    [name]="'rd'+row"
                    (change)="valueChangeMatrixTextbox($event,dataValue[row],displayColumns[i])">
                </mat-form-field>
              </td>
            </ng-container>
            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="allColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: allColumns"></tr>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```